# How the word 'destroyed' functioned here?

Tags: sentence-construction, verbs

The tsunami and the undersea earthquake which triggered it, the largest ever recorded in the region, killed nearly 20,000 people, destroyed over 100,000 homes and threw the lives of tens of millions into turmoil.

Comment: Do you see the word _and_, between the two verb phrases? Is that a hint?

Comment: I think *the largest ever recorded in the region* is ***ambiguous***, in that it could refer to either ***the undersea earthquake*** OR ***The tsunami***. Or maybe it refers to ***both of them***, since they do both seem to form the "compound noun phrase **subject**" of the verbs ***killed, destroyed, threw***.